# Content view height not increasing based on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm having a main view with UIScrollview it's child and than another view as scrollview's child. After setting the scroll view's content size it's child view's height isn't increasing.

This is the hierarchy
-MainView
--Scrollview
---ContentView

i've set the scrollview's constraint as top bottom left right to 0. 
The content view's constraints are top bottom left right to 0 and equal width and height to main view.
But the content view's height isn't increasing.

Comment: You should add some more details, like what you're trying to design.

Answer (score 0):

> The content view's constraints are top bottom left right to 0 and
>   equal width and height to main view.

**"...and height to main view"**

That's it. Your content view's height is set to equal to the screen. Let the subviews of your scrollView (or subViews of your contentView) increase the total content height so that your scrollView could scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height constraint from child view. It will make width equal to main view's width and height equal to the height of content view of scroll view.

Comment: set ContentView's priority to 250. this will let the inner labels and other controls to grow.

Comment: There is no need to add useless constraints with less priority. If you assign proper constraints to you child view of content view then content view will resize itself accordingly.